# Keyless Entity Types - EF Core still checks primary keys

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got access to view "vm_EmpNr" in database and I'am trying to reach it by keyless entity type

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(options =>
            {
                options.HasNoKey();
                options.ToView("v_EmpNr");
            });
        }
```

but despite of using "HasNoKey" in entity options I am receiving error: "The invoked method is cannot be used for the entity type 'User' because it does not have a primary key.".

My poject dependencies:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This is my first situation with keyless entity types and I don't know if maybe I miss something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Entity Framework to 3.0.1v solves a problem